# Get Guideline percent size in pixels programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I have a `GuideLine`, 15% off the left of the page.

I can get a percentage of it in this code:

```
float percent = ((ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) guideline.getLayoutParams()).guidePercent;
```

Output: 0.15

How can I get pixel or dpi values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ConstraintLayout` has already been laid out, then you can get top or left distance in pixels using `guideline.getTop()` for horizontal guideline and `guideline.getLeft()` for vertical guideline.

If `ConstraintLayout` has **not** been laid out yet (say you are in `onCreate()` of activity), then you have to wait until it is laid out:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraint);
        constraintLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Guideline guideline = findViewById(R.id.guideline);
                Log.i(TAG, guideline.getLeft() + "");
            }
        });
    }
```

**Note**, that [`getLeft()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLeft())/[`getTop()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop()) will return size in pixel. This size would point out the distance between the `Guideline` and its parent - `ConstraintLayout`. This means that value is not absolute, it's relative to its parent.

If you want to get an absolute value (say your `ConstraintLayout` is deeply nested inside view hierarchy, and you want to understand how far is the `Guideline` from the left of the screen), then you have to utilize [`View#getLocationOnScreen(int[])`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[])) API:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraint);
        constraintLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Guideline guideline = findViewById(R.id.guideline);
                int[] location = new int[2];
                guideline.getLocationOnScreen(location);
                Log.i(TAG, location[0] + " " + location[1]);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Am not find any direct conversion percentage to dp formula because phone dp is varied for multiple screen.but i have simple logic to get that value  in dp.

1) Calculate the screen width (500dp)

2) calculate the percentage of your margin (15%) of the layout width

```
float  dpvalue=totalwidth * percentage 

//500 *(0.15) =75(dpvalue)
```

this logic will  work all devices size.

Answer (score 0):

Java code:

```java
Guideline guideline = (Guideline)findViewById(R.id.guideline)
float percent = ((ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)guideline.getLayoutParams()).guidePercent
```

Kotlin code:

```
val guideline1 = findViewById<Guideline>(R.id.guideline)
val percent = (guideline1.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).guidePercent
```